# machine learning spam and ham implementation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

i recently started machine learning tutorial and very first tutorial was supervised learning (spam and ham), i started by implementing it.

```
my implementation:

---------total spam count-------------
hi free offers for you and the ! ....
5   3     9     4   4   6   8  6

---------total ham count-------------
hi free offers for you and the ! ....
3    5    3     7   3   4   6  2



mail_1 : hi! how are you here are some free offers for you !!! 

hi how are you here are some free offers for you !!! 
1  1   2   1    1   2    1    1     1    1    1   4


s[T] = c_spam(T) / ( c_spam(T) + c_ham(T) )

s[T] = how spammy is the word T
c_spam(T) = how many spam messages contain the word T
c_ham(T) = how many non-spam message contain the word T
```

**Now i have two questions:**

1) Is this implementation is correct?

2) now after the result of this machine if i found the new mail is spam then would i need to update the old spam model?

Comment: We can't tell: you haven't told us which parts are problem requirements, which are given, which parts are your choices, and which are the outputs.  Even then, where are you having trouble comparing your outputs against the expected results?  Updating the model depends on your chosen feedback mechanism.

Comment: It seems like this implementation is lacking some pieces. Even given s[T], we need some kind of activation to map the 'spammy-ness' of words to a binary classification output.